# ViewPager is blank when returning to it using back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

My application is pretty simple.
I have 1 Activity, and three fragments.
When activity is being loaded it loads fragment that consist of `ViewPager`.
I use `ViewPager` to show news, first fragment in ViewPager shows new news, the second shows read news.
Everything works good, but when I click on news and open ContentFragment to show it and then click back button to return to fragment with ViewPager. ContentFragment disappear but Fragment with ViewPager remains blank. I debugged and made sure that methods like onCreateView and etc. are being called, but fragment is still blank, I'm confused.
What is wrong with it?

**MainActivity**

```xml
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout_id">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_content">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view">
    
        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/drawer_recycler">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

On startup it shows Fragment with ViewPager

```kotlin
private fun showList() {
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val newsPagerFragment = NewsPagerFragment()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content, newsPagerFragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

**NewsPagerFragment**

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.NewsPagerFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/news_list_fragment">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout">
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ads_banner_id_test"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</LinearLayout>
```

NewsListDataFragment used in ViewPager to show news.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".fragment.NewsPagerFragment"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/news_list_fragment">
    
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/news_list_recycler"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And when we click on some news it calls

```
private fun onPreviewNewsClick(news: PostEntity) {       
        val contentFragment = NewsContentFragment()        
        val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()      
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, contentFragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }
```

NewsContentFragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".fragment.NewsContentFragment"
             android:padding="5dp"
>

   <WebView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/news_content_webview"
   >
   </WebView>

</FrameLayout>
```